# JSF selectOneMenu set null to map[key]

Tags: java, jsf, dictionary, null, selectonemenu

I want to get/set selectOneMenu value from/to map, so, I use next code xhtml:

```
<h:panelGroup id="productFilters">
<ui:repeat id="repeatSelectOneMenu"
       value="#{filterBean.productKeys}"
       var="key">
<h:selectOneMenu id="productFiltersSelector"
                 value="#{filterBean.tmp[key]}"
                 onchange="executeProductSelector();">
    <f:selectItem value="#{null}" itemLabel="#{commonBundle.all}"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{filterBean.productLists[key]}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
</ui:repeat>

<a4j:jsFunction name="executeProductSelector"
                render="productFilters"
                limitRender="true"
                execute="productFilters"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Bean:

```
public Map<Integer, String> getTmp() {
    return tmp;
}
public void setTmp(Map<Integer, String> tmp) {
    this.tmp = tmp;
}

public Map<Integer, List<String>> getProductLists() {
    return productLists;
}   
public void setProductLists(Map<Integer, List<String>> productLists) {
    this.productLists = productLists;
}

public List<Integer> getProductKeys() {
    return new ArrayList<>(getProductLists().keySet());
}
```

but, when I execute and, then, rerender it, value change to previous.
In details: suppose productKeys have just key 0 and productLists[0] contains several strings ("apple", "orange", "banana"). At current time we select "orange", then we try to choose "all". After rerender I see "orange" again and tmp[0] contain "orange" too. If I change it to "apple", everything will be ok.
My question: how can I set null to tmp[key]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not assign null value to SelectItem. if you assign it from backingbean it will raise rendering issue. but you can do it by

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="productFiltersSelector"
                 value="#{filterBean.tmp[key]}"
                 onchange="executeProductSelector();">
    <f:selectItem value="-1" itemLabel="#{commonBundle.all}"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{filterBean.productLists[key]}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

so whenever you select 'All' option, it will return -1.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. This behaviour sad and strange. If we will use simple object instead of map in selectOneMenu, null set without any problem.
Anyway. If I use value="-1" in selectItem, I catch an error, but with itemValue everything is ok. Thanks again for this workaround.